# Rails 4 Migrations are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

```
➜  BankingApp git:(master) ✗    rails generate migration AddPartNumberToProducts
➜  BankingApp git:(master) ✗ ls db/migrate
20130630195331_create_monthly_statements.rb
```

This is how I am trying to generate a migration with Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4. As you can see, the command seems to run but no file gets generated at all. Is there any reason this could be happening? Are there any command arguments I can pass to rails generate to see a better log of the errors?

Thanks.

- EDIT: With trace it still shows nothing.

  ```
  ➜  BankingApp git:(master) ✗ rails generate migration Test --trace             
  ➜  BankingApp git:(master) ✗
  ```
- EDIT #2: 
  So I manually created the file in db/migrate and it worked fine. No problems at all. But I would still like to use the generator if possible

Comment: You could try --trace option to see more info.

Comment: should create, may be you are looking for wrong file name, xcuse me if my guess i wrong

Comment: Are the files still located it db/migrate in rails 4?

Comment: @JonathanO in my Rails 4 app they are still there. I doubt, if they will ever change their location.

Comment: The file is created when I run your command in my Rails 4 app.  Are you sure 'rails' is the rails you expect and not a system rails?  Maybe try 'bundle exec rails' ?